# Scroll Top goes wrong

Tags: jquery

### scrollTop : After scrolled to bottom, it goes back to top

How to fix scrollTop? My scrolling script goes to top after scrolled to bottom. What is wrong?

Here is my jquery code :

```
$('#msgBox').animate({ scrollTop: $('#msgBox')[0].scrollHeight}, 2000);
```

Here is html :

```
<div align="left" id="msgBox">
    <div id="inIn" style="margin: 5px;">
        // conversation goes here
    </div>
</div>

<form id="chatForm" action="process.php" method="post">
    <textarea id="sendMSG"></textarea><br />
    <input type="button" id="sendBtn" value="Send"/>
</form>
```

Comment: And how can i figure out if it is not another javascript interfering ? Tell me, is it the browser that sets your #msgBox to be visible by scrolling down first, then scroll the page up ? Try putting your html on TOP of content see if it is the same behavior.

Comment: When/where does that code run? What is `#msgBox`? I suggest setting-up a JSFiddle so we can give you good advice.

Comment: ID selector does not return an array. It returns an object. get rid of `[0]`

Comment: @karthikr well $('#hlogo')[0].scrollHeight works in console on this page

Comment: Hello all friends, Thanks for reply! Actually i am working on a message box(my own created). Every time i choose a conversation it goes to bottom then top.

Comment: How to prevent scrolling to top? My english is not good please understand. :)

Comment: I will edit my question so all guies can better understand.

Comment: Please provide more detailed information as to what you're trying to do, because from your code it isn't 100% clear... That said, I believe you need to abandon using .scrollHeight and use .offset().top to determine how far from the top an element is.

Comment: Now check it guies and tell me.

Comment: #msgBox has property of style is : width:200px; height:150px; overflow:auto;